# Problems registering a folder to ArcGIS for Server 10.2.1

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2

I have ArcGIS for server 10.2.1 running and I have created an ArcGIS Server account.

This account has been given read/write access to the network at the office.

To verify this, I have logged on to a machine using the account which has been assigned to the server and connected some drive letters up to the locations of the folders I want to connect to.  I've also created folders and text files in there to make sure the account has write permissions.

I've also opened the "Configure ArcGIS Server account" utility to double check that the correct username has been assigned as the Server Account.

The problem that I'm having is that whenever I try to Register a folder to the ArcGIS server that isn't one of the local drives on the box, I get an error.

[image]

I get this regardles of wether I use the same path as the publisher path, or a different path.

But only when I try to map to a folder on the network.
Mapping to a folder on "C:" works fine.

Would anybody have any suggestions of what I could do next? Is there something really simple that I'm missing?

Comment: I've figured it out, for anybody that has the same issue or was going to provide an answer.  I was initially using a drive letter in the "Server folder path" name i.e "S:\Mapping".  However I needed to use the FULL path i.e. "\\xxxxx.gov.uk\Data\Mapping"  or "\\servername\Data\Mapping".  I hope this is useful to anybody else who has this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out, for anybody that has the same issue or was going to provide an answer. I was initially using a drive letter in the "Server folder path" name i.e "S:\Mapping". However I needed to use the FULL path i.e. "\xxxxx.gov.uk\Data\Mapping" or "\servername\Data\Mapping". I hope this is useful to anybody else who has this problem.